# Navigation instructions to users from TRUCK routes calculated with HERE-API

Tags: javascript, navigation, here-api

I don´t know from where to begin with a solution that gives TRUCK drivers a navigation from routes calculated with HERE API JS.
Is there a solution which can be integrated and receive routes for TRUCKS from HERE-API JS, or I have to build my own solution?
i appreciate any suggestions in both cases as tutorials.

Comment: I am not sure if that helps you, but check this https://youtu.be/HMwaLZJ_7ow and this https://github.com/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/truck-routing-road-restrictions

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I´m ready with the routing stage. What I´m asking for is to send the navigation instactions generated by the route to a GPS so the driver can be guided through the route.

Comment: OK, I guess you mean that you want to build your own turn-by-turn application. Check this out https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.17/dev_guide/topics/map-guidance.html and there is also an example available https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation

Comment: Probably this is the right start point :-)